# netem simulation using tc filters

Tags: filter, controls, traffic

I would like to ask for help with setting up NetEm lab using tc filters.

The situation is: there is a network, lets say 192.168.1.0/24, which should be able to access public internet. all hosts within this network are being NATed to IP 192.168.200.1. This happens on linux server with interfaces eth0 (192.168.1.1/24) and eth1 (192.168.200.1). Eth1 represents WAN link and all netem comands should be entered here.

This interface also servers for ssh access to the server. My question is how can i set up filters so all traffic from 192.168.1.0/24 will be for example delayed by 100ms, however it does not influnece management traffic to interface eth1 (192.168.200.1).

This is my current setup, however it does not work:

```
tc qdisc del dev eth1 root
tc qdisc add dev eth1 root handle 1: prio
tc filter add dev eth1 parent 1:0 protocol ip pref 55 handle 6 fw flowid 1:1
tc qdisc add dev eth1 parent 1:1 handle 6: netem delay 100ms
```

IPTABLES marking (forward mangle table):

```
 pkts bytes target    prot opt in     out     source               destination

145K  311M MARK       all  --  eth1     *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.0/24       MARK set 0x6

   0     0 MARK       all  --  eht0     *       192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            MARK set 0x6
```

appreciate any help or suggestions.Thanks a lot